# Place Order button in Checkout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

how can i edit the Place order button text in Woocommerce 
i tried

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_text','custom_order_button_text',1);
function custom_order_button_text($order_button_text) {

    $order_button_text = 'Complete Checkout';

    return $order_button_text;
}
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259838/woocommerce-change-related-products-text#31957761).

Basically, you want to use a `switch` statement hooked to the [gettext](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) filter. One benefit of this method is, if you need to change more text down the line you can just add another `case` to the function. For example:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpsx_replace_text_string', 20, 3 );
function wpsx_replace_text_string( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

  if ($domain === 'woocommerce') {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        //Text to replace
        case 'Place Order' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Complete Checkout', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
        //More text to replace
        case 'Related Products' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Other Options', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    } 
  }

  return $translated_text;
}
```

Comment: This filter hook is applied to the translated text by the internationalization functions (from Codex) and should be avoided for other uses.

Comment: @Laxmana Which codex entry are you referencing? I could be mistaken however the entry I link to above makes no mention of such a limitation. In fact the examples in it seem to suggest this is an acceptable use. See "Change the Comment Form" and "Remove Text from Admin Form"

Comment: At the `gettext` codex entry. What I want to say is that this filter is being called every time a function like `_e()` or `__()` is fired. So in a typical theme, and WordPress Admin, this kind of functions could be more than a hundred. So your filter would be fired a lot. Better to use a filter like `woocommerce_order_button_text` for better performance.